# Optimise location search mysql script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

i am trying to implement a "find nearest location" from a given latitude and longitude using mysql. i have 8000 locations stored in my wordpress website.

i managed to write this:

```
SELECT 
   b.ID, 
   SQRT( POW(69.1 * (b.latitude - 51.5073509), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-0.1277583 - b.longitude) * COS(b.latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance 
FROM 
   wp_posts a 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
   SELECT 
      post_id AS ID, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'theme_directory_map_latitude' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS latitude, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'theme_directory_map_longitude' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS longitude 
   FROM 
      wp_postmeta 
   WHERE 
      meta_key = 'theme_directory_map_latitude' OR meta_key = 'theme_directory_map_longitude' 
   GROUP BY 
      post_id 
) b ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE 
   a.post_type = 'directory' 
HAVING 
   distance < 30 
ORDER BY 
   distance
```

the script above does what i need but it takes toooo long for it to process on my weordpress site, sometimes i even get a time out error.

is there away where i can optimise the above code so it runs alot quicker?

Comment: indexing, reverse your query, don't use wordpress? this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be faster if you replace the `group by` with explicit `join`s.  This assumes that you have at most one latitude and longitude for each post:

```
SELECT b.ID, 
        SQRT( POW(69.1 * (lat.meta_value - 51.5073509), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-0.1277583 - lng.meta_value) * COS(lat.meta_value / 57.3), 2)) AS distance 
FROM wp_posts p JOIN 
     wp_postmeta lat
     on lat.post_id = p.id and lat.meta_key = 'theme_directory_map_latitude'          
     wp_postmeta lng
     on lng.post_id = p.id and lng.meta_key = 'theme_directory_map_longitude'
WHERE p.post_type = 'directory' 
HAVING distance < 30 
ORDER BY distance;
```

An index on `wp_posts(post_type, id)` would also help.  As would an index on `wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)`.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem by creating a new table which has the fields that i was trying to pull from in the joins solution.

```
SELECT
               post_id AS ID,
               featured,
               IF(latitude <> '', SQRT( POW(69.1 * (latitude - ".$lat."), 2) + POW(69.1 * (".$lng." - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)), '') AS distance
            FROM
               wp_cbk_location
            HAVING
               (distance < ".$radius." AND distance <> '') OR featured = 1
            ORDER BY
               distance
```

this solution has turned my 70s query to 0.13s, so i am happy with this solution.

i then added an post_save action hook to update wp_cbk_location everytime i save a post so the new table i created stays uptodate.

i have one remaining issue which i will submit a new question for. is there a limit to how many ids in an array i can have in a post__in?